# Google Hosted Libraries - Version Popularity vs Most Recent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

When I include a library, I am hoping that the user previously visited a site with the same script, therefore it is picked up in the cache and loads faster.

Should I not be using the most POPULAR version of the library AS OPPOSED to the most RECENT?

For example, this is the most recent [library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) for jQuery, but probably not the most popular:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How would I find the most popular version?

Answer (score 1):

Popularity should not be a factor in your choice of library versions.  Instead, you should use the one that supports the features your app needs and has been fully tested with your app.

In general as newer versions come out, they should be reviewed in terms of the features/bug-fixes they offer and balanced with the amount of development/testing needed to upgrade to that version.